# Finding a key from values (which are list) in dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dictionary:

```
x = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]}
```

and I have to extract a key based on an input. For example assume it is `3`, so my output should be `'a'`.

Here's my code:

```
x = {'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]}

n = 3

output = [k for k, v in x.items() if n in v]

print(output[0])
```

Can it be done more efficiently?

Elements in the lists are unique, i.e. the value `3` will only be in one list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given that you only want the first match, it would be more efficient to stop when you reach it:

```
output = next(key for key, value in x.items() if n in value)
```

Note that this will throw a `StopIteration` exception if there is no matching key, rather than the `IndexError` your current code throws.

If you need to do this multiple times, you could build a reverse map:

```
x_reversed = {num: key for key, value in x.items() for num in value}
```

then the lookup is a trivial `x_ reversed[n]` However, note the error case changes again, to `KeyError`.

Comment: Thanks. As I have to do it only once, I would go for the first solution.